# Magento - Is it possible to feed IE6 a different template?

Tags: magento

Just wondering if, in the config/design section of the Magento admin - where you specify templates - if it’s possible to add IE6 as an exception - so it doesn't get the custom template and falls back to using the default one?

If so, what code do you put there?

Cheers

Comment: have you looked at the instructions for the iPhone theme to see how it's installed?

Comment: Well for the iPhone it’s just “iPhone|iPod” in the matched expression box and “iPhone” as the value, but for IE6 I don’t have a clue which string/value to use - http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/ - or if it even works for browsers at all - can't really find any info on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quickest Way (not recommended)

edit this file app/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
and change preDispatch method like this:

```
public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->setArea('frontend');

        parent::preDispatch();

        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')){
            Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setTheme('default');
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: But will that not apply to all versions of IE then, not just IE6?

Comment: Ended up going with this option (of course I copied the Action.php file to the local directory first). For IE6, code is: if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.')){
Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('ie6');
};

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to add a IE 6 conditional comment in the header of your custom template and go from there. However, that'd cause, as always, a lot of headache.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but I also know that you can set templates just to show for iphones, so I reckon you must be able to specify browsers too...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would to develop a separate stylesheet just for IE6 and put in a conditional comment (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to feed IE6 said stylesheet. The only way to do as you said and have it fall back to the default is via a PHP hack (as cubny suggested) and this method is unreliable and hackish at best.

Comment: I'd only recommend this if the IE6-only design is just a tweaked version of the main design.  Otherwise, having to download a bunch of irrelevant CSS/images is a waste when this can be handled server-side.

Comment: How exactly is it irrelevant to have an additonal stylesheet for IE6? I agree it's a waste, but you can hardly blame a web developer for having to still support the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it up like the iPhone/iPod theme, but with `MSIE 6` as the search string.  Some simple testing will tell you if it's working or not :)